# Can't save image taken inside app to gallery using CameraX because "Operation not permitted"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-camerax

I'm trying to take an image inside CameraActivity and save it to the gallery. I tried following a tutorial I found online but it doesn't work, probably an issue with permissions? I tried to fix that based on other stackpverflow posts but it won't work :( The camera opens, but it doesn't take or save an image.

This is the code for CameraActivity:

```
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private TextureView view_finder;
    private Button closeCamBtn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        view_finder = findViewById(R.id.view_finder);

        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        else{
            startCamera();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }


    // always end up in onError()
    private void startCamera() {
        CameraX.unbindAll();

        Rational aspectRatio = new Rational(view_finder.getWidth(), view_finder.getHeight());
        Size screen = new Size(view_finder.getWidth(), view_finder.getHeight());

        PreviewConfig pConfig = new PreviewConfig.Builder().setTargetAspectRatio(aspectRatio).setTargetResolution(screen).build();
        Preview preview = new Preview(pConfig);

        preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener(
                output -> {
                    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view_finder.getParent();
                    parent.removeView(view_finder);
                    parent.addView(view_finder);

                    view_finder.setSurfaceTexture(output.getSurfaceTexture());
                }
        );

        ImageCaptureConfig imageCaptureConfig = new ImageCaptureConfig.Builder().setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MIN_LATENCY).
                setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()).build();

        final ImageCapture imgCap = new ImageCapture(imageCaptureConfig);

        findViewById(R.id.imgCapture).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File would be: " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            imgCap.takePicture(file, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onImageSaved(@NonNull File file) {
                    String msg = "Photo capture succeeded: " + file.getAbsolutePath();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull ImageCapture.UseCaseError useCaseError, @NonNull String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {
                    String msg = "Photo capture failed: " + message;
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(cause != null){
                        cause.printStackTrace();
                        
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview, imgCap);
    }
```

And this is the stack trace:

```
StackTrace:
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/1673950896355.jpg: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:236)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186)
W/System.err:     at androidx.camera.core.ImageSaver.run(ImageSaver.java:75)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)*/
(...)
```

Here's the manifest permissions:

```
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/1673950896355.jpg: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Dont try to save your file in root of external storage.

Put an image file in public DCIM or Pictures directory. Like:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
```

And on Android 10- devices you need to request WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission at runtime too.